# Need to translate windows command to bash script

Tags: bash, batch-file

I need to translate the following windows command to bash:

```
echo %BUCKET%
cd %script_folder%
if not exist "venv" (virtualenv -p C:\Python37\python.exe venv)
cd venv\Scripts\
call activate
cd ..\..\
pip install -r requirements.txt
pause
```

What I came with was:

```
echo %BUCKET%
cd %script_folder%
   #if not exist "venv" (virtualenv -p C:\Python37\python.exe venv) -- How?
cd venv/Scripts/
   #call activate -- How?
cd ../../
pip install -r requirements.txt | less
```

I am not sure the conversion is correct and in any case I do not know how to convert the "How?" labeled rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo $BUCKET
cd $script_folder

if [ ! -d venv ]; then
    python3 -m venv venv
fi

source venv/bin/activate
python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt | less
```

Comment: Thank you for answering despite of others voting for closing the question! I appreciate that!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "$BUCKET"
cd "$script_folder"
[ ! -d venv ] && python3 -m venv venv
bash --init-file <(echo ". venv/bin/activate; pip install -r requirements.txt;")
```

Don't forget to make it executable:

```
chmod +x thescript.sh
```

Comment: Thank you for answering despite of others voting for closing the question! I appreciate that!!!